# Angular/cli not installed properly

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I install angular/cli I get the following:

```
$ npm install  @angular/cli

npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'sandbox2\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'sandbox2\package.json'
npm WARN sandbox2 No description
npm WARN sandbox2 No repository field.
npm WARN sandbox2 No README data
npm WARN sandbox2 No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.3 
(node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@1.2.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

This is a continuation of the insallation above. I am forced to add more comments here;

```
+ @angular/cli@6.1.0
updated 1 package in 54.164s
[!] 4 vulnerabilities found [22842 packages audited]
    Severity: 1 Low | 3 Moderate
    Run `npm audit` for more detail
```

Then creating a project fails:

```
$ ng new hd12
newTree.optimize is not a function
```

Comment: Try this, npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: And Then, ng new hd12

Comment: I'm not sure it will solve issue, but @angular/cli should be installed globally `npm install -g @angular/cli`. Could you try this from an other directory ?

Comment: @ A. SakkeerI still get the error: $ ng new hd12
newTree.optimize is not a function

Answer (score 4):

Problem is with the latest version of angular/cli.
$npm install  @angular/cli@latest

Used last known working version:
 npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@6.1.0-rc.0

Comment: I can confirm the same fix for me. Even 6.1.1 still has the problem. rc0 is the only version I can get to work correctly.

Comment: Confirm, I had the same issue and now it is resolved in this version.